# Search by group in mongoose and find based on criteria (Node, Express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate

```
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.2.2",
```

I have a server running on Express on top of Node and using Mongoose to handle MongoDB.
One of my collections in MongoDB has this structure:

```
[
  ...
  ...
  ...,
  {
  _id: 64817b7d47af9b7e12e6cb5b
  userId: 647f8f9037c28e47a23c02c0
  flips: 19
  milliseconds: 18616
  updatedAt: 2023-06-12T10:00:40.833+00:00
  __v: 0
  },
  {
  _id: 64817b7d47af9b7e12e6cb5c
  userId: 647f8f9037c28e47a23c02c0
  flips: 20
  milliseconds: 18616
  updatedAt: 2023-06-12T10:00:40.833+00:00
  __v: 0
  },
  {
  _id: 64817b7d47af9b7e12e6cb5d
  userId: 647f8f9037c28e47a23c02c1
  flips: 19
  milliseconds: 18616
  updatedAt: 2023-06-12T10:00:40.833+00:00
  __v: 0
  },
  {
  _id: 64817b7d47af9b7e12e6cb5e
  userId: 647f8f9037c28e47a23c02c1
  flips: 19
  milliseconds: 18716
  updatedAt: 2023-06-12T10:00:40.833+00:00
  __v: 0
  },
  ...
  ...
  ...
]
```

This collection keeps the 5 best scores of all users.

What i want is to make a query asking from Mongoose to return the best score for each userId based on milliseconds. If milliseconds are equal then based on flips and if flips are equal based on which document inserted first. I tried with aggregation and $group to keep a unique record for each userId but couldn't figure out how to add conditions. Is this possible and if yes can i paginate over this?

Comment: $sort first based on all of your conditions then group on userId (probably using $first and $$ROOT)

Comment: ... or using `"$top"` within `"$group"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = await YourModel.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      userId: 1, // Sort by userId in ascending order
      milliseconds: 1, // Sort by milliseconds in ascending order
      flips: 1, // Sort by flips in ascending order
      updatedAt: 1 // Sort by updatedAt in ascending order
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      bestScore: { $first: "$$ROOT" } // Select the first document in each group
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$bestScore" } // Replace the root document with the bestScore document
  }
]);
```

```
 {
    _id: new ObjectId("64817c0547af9b7e12e6cb7f"),
    userId: new ObjectId("647f8f9037c28e47a23c02c0"),
    flips: 32,
    milliseconds: 14547,
    updatedAt: 2023-06-08T06:57:03.479Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("648874da4ff7074debb99428"),
    flips: 34,
    milliseconds: 12800,
    updatedAt: 2023-06-08T06:54:03.479Z,
    userId: new ObjectId("647f8f9037c28e47a23c02c2"),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("648872f24ff7074debb99427"),
    flips: 14,
    milliseconds: 18800,
    updatedAt: 2023-06-08T06:54:03.479Z,
    userId: new ObjectId("647f8f9037c28e47a23c02c1"),
    __v: 0
  }
```

In this case it works but not identically because i want the results to be sorted based on the same criteria, because i want to use also pagination.